# Applying for 2 UK visas simultaneously

Tags: visas

I'm in a time crunch applying for 3 visas in 7 weeks... Do you think I can apply for a **UK visitor in transit visa** and a **UK Tier 4 study visa** at the same time? That'd save a lot of time.

Comment: Good question. I do not know the answer, but you should consider that depending on the details of your itineraries you may not need the visitor in transit visa.

Comment: @phoog nice one, that comment is an answer; and don't forget that the rules prohibit having more than one permission at a time.

Comment: @GayotFow does that prohibition apply to visas with non-overlapping periods of validity?

Comment: @phoog no it does not. I covers that a person cannot have more than one permission at the same time.

Comment: Please be clear with your question.

i) Applying for any type of visa for any country depends on your nationality,

ii) You can't submit 2 applications at a time or 1 application for 2 types of UK visa.

iii) Might be your passport don't require visa in transit.